# Excel 2013 vba created workbook opens for users in "Protected View"

Tags: excel, vba

I have VBA code that spins through a worksheet and creates workbooks that are emailed to clients.  It's pretty simple, really, it writes the output files to My Documents.  Here is the save code:

```
With wkbOutputBook
.CheckCompatibility = False
.Save
.Close
End With
```

When the worksbook is opened, Excel says:

PROTECTED VIEW Office has detected a problem with this file.  Editing it may harm your computer.  Click for more details.

OK I know what this means, for reasons unknown Excel thinks this file was sent through Outlook, or downloaded from the Internet.  But it wasn't.  I've tried the following:

Save in different versions/file formats

Use Save As instead of Save

Explicitly turn off protected mode.  Protected mode isn't the same thing as Protected View though.

Surely "My Documents" isn't considered an "unsafe" location.

Thanks.

Comment: Is there code in the Workbooks you're creating?  If so, have you tried [digitally signing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Digitally-sign-your-macro-project-956e9cc8-bbf6-4365-8bfa-98505ecd1c01) them?

Answer (score 0):

If you can accept files being saved in read only mode, this should probably eliminate an error message.

```
Dim path As String

path = "full-path-with-filename-and-extension"

With wkbOutputBook
  .SaveCopyAs (path)
  SetAttr (path), vbReadOnly
  .Close
End With
```

You try .SaveCopyAs (path) method without code line involving setting read only, but I guess it won't help.

What format do you try to save your file as? Does the problem appear only on your PC or have You tested your macro / output files on other PCs? The problem can involve stuff in system registry.

Comment: No change, but thanks for trying.  I had to close/save/set file attribute as I am creating the workbook "on the fly" in the code, it wouldn't let me SaveAs because it had never been saved.  I'm saving in the default format, I tried various formats (Excel9, Excel9597, etc) they all had the same results.  It's some new "trust" feature I suppose...